# Why so many TCPv6 objects in slab when I run my Netty Application

Tags: java, linux, netty

I have a netty application to hold about 1,500,000 long connections. When I did this , I used 'slabtop' and found there are 1,500,000 TCPv6 objects in slab(about 3GB), But I didn't use IPv6 at all, All the connections based on IPv4 extactly. Why?

update: My server is CentOS 5.5, Linux version 2.6.18-194.el5(x86_64) and I use Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM to run my application

Comment: what netstat -an says about the connections ?

Comment: and are the "1,500,000" connections incoming or outgoing ?